# Can Haskell optimize function calls the same way Clang / GCC does?

Tags: c++, performance, haskell, optimization, llvm

I want to ask you if Haskell and C++ compilers can optimize function calls the same way.
Please look at following codes. In the following example Haskell is significantly faster than C++.

I have heard that Haskell can compile to LLVM and can be optimized by the LLVM passes. Additionally I have heard that Haskell has some heavy optimizations under the hood.
But the following examples should be able to work with the same performance.
I want to ask:

1. Why my sample benchmark in C++ is slower than the on in Haskell?
2. is it possible to further optimize the codes?

(I'm using LLVM-3.2 and GHC-7.6).

C++ code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

int b(const int x){
    return x+5;
}

int c(const int x){
    return b(x)+1;
}

int d(const int x){
    return b(x)-1;
}

int a(const int x){
    return c(x) + d(x);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    printf("Starting...\n");
    long int iternum = atol(argv[1]);
    long long int out = 0;
    for(long int i=1; i<=iternum;i++){
        out += a(iternum-i);
    }
    printf("%lld\n",out);
    printf("Done.\n");
}
```

compiled with `clang++ -O3 main.cpp`

haskell code:

```
module Main where
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import System.Environment
b :: Int -> Int
b x = x + 5
c x = b x + 1
d x = b x - 1
a x = c x + d x
main = do
   putStrLn "Starting..."
   args <- getArgs
   let iternum = read (head args) :: Int in do
      putStrLn $ show $ V.foldl' (+) 0 $ V.map (\i -> a (iternum-i))
         $ V.enumFromTo 1 iternum
      putStrLn "Done."
```

compiled with `ghc -O3 --make -fforce-recomp -fllvm ghc-test.hs`

speed results:

[image]

```
Running testcase for program 'cpp/a.out'
-------------------
cpp/a.out 100000000      0.0%   avg time: 105.05 ms 
cpp/a.out 200000000      11.11% avg time: 207.49 ms 
cpp/a.out 300000000      22.22% avg time: 309.22 ms 
cpp/a.out 400000000      33.33% avg time: 411.7 ms 
cpp/a.out 500000000      44.44% avg time: 514.07 ms 
cpp/a.out 600000000      55.56% avg time: 616.7 ms 
cpp/a.out 700000000      66.67% avg time: 718.69 ms
cpp/a.out 800000000      77.78% avg time: 821.32 ms 
cpp/a.out 900000000      88.89% avg time: 923.18 ms 
cpp/a.out 1000000000     100.0% avg time: 1025.43 ms


Running testcase for program 'hs/main'
-------------------
hs/main 100000000    0.0%   avg time: 70.97 ms (diff: 34.08)
hs/main 200000000    11.11% avg time: 138.95 ms (diff: 68.54)
hs/main 300000000    22.22% avg time: 206.3 ms (diff: 102.92)
hs/main 400000000    33.33% avg time: 274.31 ms (diff: 137.39)
hs/main 500000000    44.44% avg time: 342.34 ms (diff: 171.73)
hs/main 600000000    55.56% avg time: 410.65 ms (diff: 206.05)
hs/main 700000000    66.67% avg time: 478.25 ms (diff: 240.44)
hs/main 800000000    77.78% avg time: 546.39 ms (diff: 274.93)
hs/main 900000000    88.89% avg time: 614.12 ms (diff: 309.06)
hs/main 1000000000   100.0% avg time: 682.32 ms (diff: 343.11)
```

**EDIT**
Of course we cannot compare speed of languages, but the speed of implementiations.

**But I'm curious if Ghc and C++ compilers can optimize function calls the same way**

**I've edited the question with new benchmark and codes based on your help :)**

Comment: You're comparing inequivalent code, which makes the benchmark useless. (Also it's a benchmark against specific implementations, not languages; languages don't have speed.)

Comment: Any chance you can post the assembly code that is generated by these two compilers? In particular, look for inlining.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus - of course languages does not have "speed". Could you please show me the equivalent Haskell code?

Comment: How is that not C code?

Comment: @chrisaycock how can I generate LLVM IR (assembly) from ghc? I was looking for this for long.

Comment: Use `foldl'` from `Data.List` instead of `foldl`.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez: In this case, it doesn't seem to make a difference. At least it didn't on my machine with GHC 7.0.4 (I'm at work :P).

Comment: As noted in my downvoted answer, the C program with decent optimization doesn't actually run the loop, it just works out the answer at compile time.  "+ g++-4.8 -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -pthread main.cpp

main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:

main.cpp:16:22: warning: iteration 1073741818u invokes undefined behavior [-Waggressive-loop-optimizations]

     return c(x) + d(x);"

                      ^

main.cpp:22:5: note: containing loop

     for(long int i=1; i<=2000000000;i++){

     ^

+ ./a.out

Starting...

4000000022000000000

Done.

Comment: If you want to avoid testing against `printf(answer)`, with all the work done at compile time, you might want to read the number of iterations in from an external source not known at compile time.

Comment: @Yakk: ghc with fusion and llvm does the same

Comment: I think you need to write `i <= atoi(argv[1])` in your C++ code, otherwise it would be `movabsq $10000001100000000, %rdx; movl $.LC1, %esi; movl $1, %edi; xorl %eax, %eax; call __printf_chk`, i.e. no loops at all (Yakk is right in his comment). And, yes, just use strict recursion with accumulators on `Int`'s for loop-like constructions, not `map`, `fold*`, etc (which works on lazy lists, can be fused together, but not always).

Comment: I've updated the question and the results.

Comment: The edited question is radically different from the original question. I consider that bad practice, as it invalidates existing answers.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If your goal is to get this running as quickly as your C++ compiler, then you
would want to use a data structure that the compiler can have its way with.

```
module Main where

import qualified Data.Vector as V

b :: Int -> Int
b x = x + 5
c x = b x + 1
d x = b x - 1

a x = c x + d x

main = do
    putStrLn "Starting..."
    putStrLn $ show $ V.foldl' (+) 0 $ V.map a $ V.enumFromTo 1 100000000
    putStrLn "Done."
```

GHC is able to completely eliminate the loop and just inserts a constant into
the resulting assembly. On my computer, this now has a runtime of < 0.002s, when
using the same optimization flags as you originally specified.

As a follow up based on the comments by @Yuras, the core produced by the
vector based solution and the stream-fusion solution are functionally
identical.

## Vector

```
main_$s$wfoldlM'_loop [Occ=LoopBreaker]
  :: Int# -> Int# -> Int#

main_$s$wfoldlM'_loop =
  \ (sc_s2hW :: Int#) (sc1_s2hX :: Int#) ->
    case <=# sc1_s2hX 100000000 of _ {
      False -> sc_s2hW;
      True ->
        main_$s$wfoldlM'_loop
          (+#
             sc_s2hW
             (+#
                (+# (+# sc1_s2hX 5) 1)
                (-# (+# sc1_s2hX 5) 1)))
          (+# sc1_s2hX 1)
    }
```

## stream-fusion

```
$wloop_foldl [Occ=LoopBreaker]
  :: Int# -> Int# -> Int#

$wloop_foldl =
  \ (ww_s1Rm :: Int#) (ww1_s1Rs :: Int#) ->
    case ># ww1_s1Rs 100000000 of _ {
      False ->
        $wloop_foldl
          (+#
             ww_s1Rm
             (+#
                (+# (+# ww1_s1Rs 5) 1)
                (-# (+# ww1_s1Rs 5) 1)))
          (+# ww1_s1Rs 1);
      True -> ww_s1Rm
    }
```

The only real difference is the choice of comparison operation for the
termination condition. Both versions compile to tight tail recursive loops
that can be easily optimized by LLVM.

Comment: That's strange, but your version takes exactly the same time as mine... I expected it to be much faster. Could you please compare them with llvm?

Comment: @Yuras, that is probably because it is now as fast as it can get. Odds are that in both versions, GHC+LLVM was able to compute the result at compile time and just inserted that into the assembly. Without LLVM, the result is not precomputed, but they probably produce equivalent loops.

Comment: Thank you for such clarification. I don't accept the answer, because with this solution we are getting different situation - C++ i much slower - I would love to investigate why.

Comment: @danilo2, I am unable to replicate the results you posted. My benchmarks result in the C++ version usually having about 90% the execution time of the Haskell code.

Comment: @danilo2, I used the flags provided in your post. What version of llvm are you using?

Comment: @sabauma, I've tested these codes under LLVM 3.2 and 3.3 giving the same results (under Gentoo Linux x64 - but I dont think this could someway affect the performance)

Comment: @danilo2, we are using the same versions of LLVM and GHC. I cannot think of a reason why they would produce such markedly different results.

Comment: @sabauma could you please send me your system spec (architecture, os etc) and the speed results for input of `1000000000` - i would love to investigate it further.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32693/discussion-between-sabauma-and-danilo2)

Answer (score 10):

ghc doesn't fuse lists (avoiding success at all costs?)

Here is version that uses [stream-fusion](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/stream-fusion) package:

```
module Main where

import Prelude hiding (map, foldl)
import Data.List.Stream
import Data.Stream (enumFromToInt, unstream)
import Text.Printf
import Control.Exception
import System.CPUTime

b :: Int -> Int
b x = x + 5
c x = b x + 1
d x = b x - 1

a x = c x + d x

main = do
    putStrLn "Starting..."
    putStrLn $ show $ foldl (+) 0 $ map (\z -> a z) $ unstream $ enumFromToInt 1 100000000 
    putStrLn "Done."
```

I don't have llvm installed to compare with your results, but it is 10x faster then your version (compiled without llvm).

I think vector fusion should perform even faster.

Comment: Its not entirely correct to say GHC does not fuse lists. GHC uses [shortcut fusion](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Correctness_of_short_cut_fusion) to eliminate some intermediates. Based on [this](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.1/html/users_guide/rewrite-rules.html), I don't think `foldl` is considered a good consumer and cannot be fused into a loop as a result. The stream-fusion and vector libraries clearly can fuse foldl.

Answer (score 7):

As others have pointed out, you're not comparing equivalent algorithms.  As [Yuras pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17345377/166732) GHC doesn't fuse lists.  Your Haskell version will actually allocate that entire list, it will be done lazily one cell at a time, but it will be done.  Below is a version that's algorithmically closer to your C version.  On my system it runs in the same time as the C version.

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
module Main where

import Text.Printf
import Control.Exception
import System.CPUTime
import Data.List

a,b,c :: Int -> Int
b x = x + 5
c x = b x + 1
d x = b x - 1

a !x = c x + d x

-- Don't allocate a list, iterate and increment as the C version does.
applyTo !acc !n
    | n > 100000000 = acc
    | otherwise = applyTo (acc + a n) (n + 1)

main = do
    putStrLn "Starting..."
    print $ applyTo 0 1
    putStrLn "Done."
```

Comparing it with `time`:

```
    ghc -O3 bench.hs -fllvm -fforce-recomp -o bench-hs && time ./bench-hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( bench.hs, bench.o )
Linking bench-hs ...
Starting...
10000001100000000
Done.
./bench-hs  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 0.003 total
```

Compared to C:

```
clang++ -O3 bench.cpp -o bench && time ./bench                                   
Starting...
10000001100000000
Done.
./bench  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 0.004 total
```

Comment: Well that's embarrassing, doesn't change the times though. Thanks and Fixed :)